# How i create a table from a list of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

i have a really hard work and i don't know how to implement it in T-SQL (SQL Server).

I have a table (TEMP_TABLE) like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Measure     Column_Name     Column_Type    TableToBeCreated 
-------------------------------------------------------------  
ME_AA       D_Product     [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEAA
ME_AA       D_Store       [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEAA
ME_AA1      D_Product     [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEAA
ME_AA1      D_Store       [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEAA
ME_BB       D_Product     [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
ME_BB       D_Store       [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
ME_BB       D_Time        [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
ME_BB1      D_Product     [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
ME_BB1      D_Store       [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
ME_BB1      D_Time        [decimal](19,6)  STAGIN_MEBB
.
..
...
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then, from that table, i want to create a table called as the column TableToBeCreated from TEMP_TABLE like this:

1) Table STAGIN_MEAA:

```
------------------------------------------
D_Product     D_Store     ME_AA    ME_AA1 ...... ME_AAx
------------------------------------------
```

The data type of the ME_AA columns must be the same from the column "Column_Type" from TEMP_TABLE.

2) Table STAGIN_MEBB:

```
------------------------------------------
D_Product     D_Store     D_Store    ME_BB     ME_BB1 ...... MEBBx 
------------------------------------------
```

The data type of the ME_AA columns must be the same from the column "Column_Type" from TEMP_TABLE.

How can i generate a code for the creation of this ME_ tables?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into using a Pivot.

Comment: Sorry about the "2) Table STAGIN_MEBB:", there's an error, the table must be like this:

------------------------------------------
D_Product     D_Store     D_Time   ME_BB     ME_BB1 ...... MEBBx 
------------------------------------------

Comment: Can you add exact desired script of  STAGIN_MEAA to the question? I cant get Measure column...

Comment: I want a script like:

CREATE TABLE STAGIN_MEAA (
D_PRODUCT BIGINT,
D_STORE BIGINT,
ME_AA  [decimal](19,6),
ME_AA1  [decimal](19,6),
.
..
...
ME_AAX [decimal](19,6)
)

Comment: if ME_AA  is also a column to be created why dont u give these as rows like "D_Product"?. Because tihs structure is hard to process

Comment: Could be, or i can create the ME_AA table without the ME_AA column, then i can do a distinct to that field and create another script to add columns to the STAGIN_MEAA table created before?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script. I omitted "Measure" column. I've tested it. You can alter script due to the sql server you use.

```
create table #x(
    id numeric(10) identity,
    col_name varchar(64),
    col_type varchar(64),
    table_name varchar(64)
)
delete #x
insert #x select 'D_Product','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEAA'
insert #x select 'D_Store  ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEAA'
insert #x select 'D_Product','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEAA'
insert #x select 'D_Store  ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEAA'
insert #x select 'D_Product','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'
insert #x select 'D_Store  ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'
insert #x select 'D_Time   ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'
insert #x select 'D_Product','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'
insert #x select 'D_Store  ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'
insert #x select 'D_Time   ','[decimal](19,6)','STAGIN_MEBB'

create table #y(
    line varchar(100)
)

delete from #y
declare @min_id numeric(10),
         @name varchar(64),
         @type varchar(64),
         @table varchar(64),
         @old_table varchar(64),
         @script varchar(1000)
select @min_id = 1

while @min_id is not null
begin
    select @name = col_name, @type = col_type, @table = table_name from #x where id = @min_id

    if @old_table is not null and @old_table != @table 
        insert #y select ") " + char(13) + char(10) +  "go" 

    if @old_table != @table
        insert #y select "create table " + @table + "("

    if @old_table = @table
        insert #y   select " ," + @name + " " + @type
    else
        insert #y   select "  " + @name + " " + @type

    select @old_table = @table
    select @min_id = min(id) from #x where id > @min_id
end

insert #y select ")"
insert #y select "go"

select line from #y

drop table #x
drop table #y
```

Result:

```
line                                                                                                 
----                                                                                                 
create table STAGIN_MEAA(                                                                            
  D_Product [decimal](19,6)                                                                          
 ,D_Store [decimal](19,6)                                                                            
 ,D_Product [decimal](19,6)                                                                          
 ,D_Store [decimal](19,6)                                                                            
) 
go                                                                                               
create table STAGIN_MEBB(                                                                            
  D_Product [decimal](19,6)                                                                          
 ,D_Store [decimal](19,6)                                                                            
 ,D_Time [decimal](19,6)                                                                             
 ,D_Product [decimal](19,6)                                                                          
 ,D_Store [decimal](19,6)                                                                            
 ,D_Time [decimal](19,6)                                                                             
)                                                                                                    
go
```